# How to rewrite a URI in Grails within UrlMappings.groovy

Tags: grails, redirect, groovy, url-rewriting, url-mapping

I would like to basically do a URL rewrite in UrlMappings.groovy, for example:

```
"/pub/cdn/$version/**"(uri: request.forwardURI.replaceFirst("/pub/cdn/[0-9]*", ""))
```

So that a request for:

```
/pub/cdn/1327516405188/css/login.css
```

for example, would get translated to:

```
/css/login.css
```

The idea is to take the original URI and strip out some of the path, and pass along the new URI.

However, using the above code, I get the error:

```
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>    creating bean with name 'grailsUrlMappingsHolder': Cannot resolve
>    reference to bean 'urlMappingsTargetSource' while setting bean
>    property 'targetSource'; nested exception is
>    ...
>    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: forwardURI for
>    class: java.lang.String
```

which seems to imply that the request object is a String. Is there a way to obtain the original URI in UrlMappings.groovy?

The "/old/path"(uri: "/new/path") method does work as long as the new path is hard coded, but I can't figure out how to access the original requested path as a variable inside the UrlMappings class.

P.S. I tried having UrlMappings call a controller:

```
"/pub/cdn/$version/**" {
    controller = "image"
    action = "cdnRedirect"
}
```

and in the Controller:

```
def cdnRedirect = {
    def newUri = request.forwardURI?.toString().replaceFirst("/pub/cdn/[0-9]*", "")
    return redirect(uri: newUri)
}
```

While the controller closure gets called correctly, and the URI gets translated correctly, the redirect does not seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, it sounds to me like you are solving the wrong issue.  The real issue here is seems to be that you are using relative links (e.g. `css/login.css`) to static content.  When the browser picks up a relative link, it uses the current url to determine the file's path.

However, if you use Grails' [`resource` tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/resource.html), grails will generate a URL that is anchored to the root of the URL.  For example, your `css/login.css` link would become `/myAppName/css/login.css`.

Usage is like so:

```
<link type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'login.css')}" />
```

This guarantees that, no matter the controller, action, or other ID information, the link to the CSS file will always be correct.

---

As for why your UrlMapping isn't working, it's because it isn't dynamically processed.  It's processed during application startup, and so the `request` object doesn't even exist at that time.

If you absolutely need a URL rewriting system, and using a controller to process the resources is too complex for this purpose, I recommend putting your servlet engine (i.e. Tomcat) behind Apache and just using `mod_rewrite`.  Properly designed, however, this really shouldn't be necessary.

---

**Edit**

Just for complete information, to get dynamic control of the mapping is to use the syntax specified in [Dynamic Controller and Action Names](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#embeddedVariables).  However, this is somewhat limited, and you still can't use it to perform a redirect.

Comment: Thank you - this is great advice, especially the insight that the request object doesn't exist when UrlMappings is processed! As for whether I'm trying to solve the wrong problem, I'm not sure - I am basically trying to "fool" a CDN to refresh its cache by passing it different (versioned) URIs for the same resource, but I wanted the grails application (sitting behind the CDN) to translate, for example: `/pub/cdn/[any number]/css/login.css` to actually pull from `/css/login.css` regardless of the content of [any number].

Comment: For that, I would probably go the `mod_rewrite` route, if that's possible. The only other suggestion is to try explicit URI remapping, but I don't know it's capabilities regarding wildcards: `"/hello"(uri: "/hello.dispatch")`.  It's from the [first section on UrlMappings](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToControllersAndActions).